# Is there a way to count the number of points within a certain area on a graph?

Tags: python

I've got output graphs that look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLspP.png]

My question is, is there an easy way for me to count the number of points within each of the obvious 'lines' or 'streaks' of particles? In other words, I need to find the density of each of the streaks separately. Most of them are overlapping which is where my issue comes in.

I've tried specifying x and y limits but again, the overlapping comes into play. The existing code is just importing and plotting values.

Comment: You could try [Hierarchical Clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering), which should allow you to group together the points in each streak, then do analysis on those clusters (like count the points)

Comment: Instead of strict x and y limits you could use line equations to separate your clusters.  By defining lines that separate the clusters , you can check if your data point is below one line and above another.  Unfortunately you'd have to define the lines manually so you might want a more automated fix.

Answer (score 0):

Ken, thanks for your comment. I went along that path, I found that single linkage works best for the type of clusters I have. I also had to find a multiplying factor for my own data first, because the clustering was failing with the data overlapping. [image: The adjusted data] With this data the different colours represent different clusters. The dendrogram x-axis is labelled with the cluster densities, but they aren't in order! I'm yet to find an efficient way around this. I manually adjusted the dendrogram to produce 2 clusters first, which told me the density of the first shell (it produced 2 clusters, 1 of the first shell and 1 with everything else). Then repeated it for 3,4, etc. 
Sorry if none of this makes sense! It's quite late/early here.